# express.static() only working with index not with other pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning nodejs and in it I'm in `express.static` when I call `style.css` in express it working fine in index but not in all other pages.

My directory looks like this.

```
app folder/
├── assets/
│   └── style.css
├── views/
│   ├── index.ejs
│   ├── contact.ejs
│   ├── profile.ejs
│   └── 404.ejs
└── express.js
```

My code of `express.js` is

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
app.set('view engine','ejs'); 
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){ 
  res.render('index');
});
app.get('/contact',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.query);
  res.render('contact');
});
app.get('/profile/:name', function(req,res){
  var data = {age: 16,job: 'study',hobbies: ['learn', 'swim', 'read']}
  res.render('profile',{person: req.params.name, data: data}); 
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Where is your index file in the directory, and where is the file you're unable to access style.css from?

Comment: `express.static()` allows you to serve static files.
If you set "assets", that means you must have all your render files in that directory..
I'm not sure about `app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));` either. @schu34 is right: where are all your files?

Comment: How does the `<link>` in the final html code look like that loads the `style.css` ? Do you see an error message in the developer console about loading `style.css` and if so what error message?

Comment: @t.niese nope there is not any error

Comment: And the first part of my question?

Comment: Opps problem is solved. I wrote <link> only in index not in all after writing in all pages it's working fine thank you so much specially @t.niese

Comment: Oh so good, your problem is solved.
But you should use `app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')))` instead of that way, if you run `node` from folder don't same your `express.js` file, It will have error.